# What image information is considered a good idea to store in a MySQL database for example?

Tags: mysql

I am going to store the images in folders and not in the database. But the information about the images will be stored in the database. For now the image table looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS database.image;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.image (
    id                      INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    filename                VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    extension               VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    created                 INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    user_id                 INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    deleted                 INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE database.image ADD INDEX (user_id);
```

Is there any point of saving say for example size of the image for the future? Or maybe storing dimensions would be a good idea? What is considered worth saving as information for the future in an image table like this?

I will probably need to store some kind of thumbnails too. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you save should depend on how you plan to use the data in the future.

If you just need to show the list of the images sorted by name then filename is enough.

In case you want to add advanced image filtration in the future i.e. filter images list by size, type, dimensions then it is reasonable to extract all these information from image when you create it and store to the DB.

Thumbnails could be generated at the stage when you create an image. Add thumbnail name to the database as well if you need to refer to it in your application.

I think it is a good practice not to store path in the database. I.e. don't store path to the image as /var/www/public/uploads/myimage.jpg . In this case if you move to another server where your web site will be located at /home/cheaphosting/public you will have problems. Save either filename or related path to the DB and configure the absolute path in the application.

Comment: I concur with the recommendation to store the filename with a "relative" path, relative to a base images directory. The base of the uri should come from the webserver configuration. (You probably do not want to store thousands and thousands of image files in a single filesystem, because of the way filesystem directories become unwieldy (i.e. *very slow*) when there are lots of files.